# How to fix 400 Bad Request for JavaScript fetch API PUT

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, put, fetch-api

I am making a PUT request to my rails server to update an item in an items array. My item includes id, name, and description. When I make the PUT request I get a response 400 Bad Request. Additionally, I get this error:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: item):
>   app/controllers/api/v1/items_controller.rb:24:in 'item_params'
>   app/controllers/api/v1/items_controller.rb:17:in 'update'

I have tried to format the request in different ways to see if the item is not being properly formatted. I have looked up similar posts but they do not seem to cover my exact request method or do not show a similar type of object.

My current function to update looks like this:

```
 handleUpdate = (item) => {
    const id = item.id;
    fetch(`/api/v1/items/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'item': item
      })
    }).then(() => {
      this.updateItems(item);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Here is my items_controller:

```
def update
    item = Item.find(params["id"])
    item.update_attributes(item_params)
    respond_with item, json: item
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:id, :name, :description)
  end
```

Here is the object I made with the call to the handleUpdate function:

```
const item = {
        'id': id,
        'name': this.state.name,
        'description': this.state.description
      };
      this.props.handleUpdate(item);
```

My state is being updated correctly but the error prevents my database from updating the item correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are requiring "item" in `params.require(:item)`, your requests needs a parent "item" key

```
{"item": { "id": id, "name": "somename", "description": "some desc." }}
```

Comment: Actually, this was just a piece of what I needed to do. I added a header with content-type of application/json and that worked out fine. Thanks for the help.